# how to control mouse movement in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, controls, mouseevent

I am doing a project where a regular monitor could be converted into a touchscreen.
For this purpose i have designed a grid of ir sensors and installed them into a frame that could be put around the screen. That concludes the hardware.

What i want to do is control the mouse movement using the grid, so that when the user moves his/her finger inside the frame it moves the mouse on the screen. Thus giving the effect of a touchscreen. I hope I am clear in explaining my problem. I am using Windows,MS Visual C++.

If there is any suggestion other than visual C++, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394.aspx) function.

Comment: This is the trivial part. Hard part is converting the ir data to something sensible. Question is too vague to answer  in its current state.

Comment: well the ir sensors send the x,y coords to the serial port. I am using arduino to read the ir sensors output and i can see the respected x,y coords in the terminal when a particular ir sensor is blocked. I dont know if that helps.

Comment: And which part of the question is vague, so that i can add more to it. Thank you.

Comment: Would it make a difference if i use MOUSEINPUT's dx,dy rather than SetCursorPosition? Thank you